# Why share pipe sends two the same requests?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, rxjs6

My http service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class HttpService {
  public blocks$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.blocks$ = this.http
      .get("URL")
      .pipe(share());
  }
}
```

In the parent component, I subscribe to receive data:

```
 forkJoin([this.httpService.blocks$]).subscribe(() => {})
```

And after in child component is acync:

```
*ngFor="let block of httpService.blocks$  | async"
```

Why do I see two requests in network, why share() does not work?

Parent component has child component inside and activated by `*ngIf`

Comment: Maybe you have two instances of the HttpService. Do you use HttpService as provider (in the decorator) inside the component?

Comment: I think what you looking for is .shareReplay(), also no need to fork join just one observable

Comment: Yes, but id use shareReplay in singltone service it still calls twice, first parent component, then child. How to fix it?

Comment: I have onle one HttpService in system

Comment: I don't know how to solve this but if the parent component has the data, why don't you pass it down in the child component as an `@Input()`? This way you will only see one network call and you're passing down the data.

Comment: I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3cfrjw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to reproduce your behaviour. IMHO you two instances of HttpService in your application (look the example in the stackblitz project in the hello.component.ts). An instance is created via an injector, check-in your code if use `providers` or `viewProviders` @Component configuration. I hope it will help you.